# Network Error when initiating a query to my graphql API

Tags: heroku, graphql, apollo, apollo-boost

Here's the error message I get when doing a query :

`[Network error]: ServerParseError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

The query works fine locally, when setting the uri of my ApolloClient to `http://localhost:4000/graphql`, and running the server locally.

However, if I deploy my server to heroku, then set the client's uri to `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/` it does not work, I get the error message above. The network tab shows a 404 to the POST request to my heroku app, "cannot POST"

The heroku logs show no error upon pushing.

Any idea what I am missing here ? I have checked all the tutorials I could find, and I don't see anything obvious missing.

Here's my client request :

`const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com/',
  headers: {
    authorization: "Bearer API_KEY",
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the URI be `uri: https://my-app.herokuapp.com/graphql` ? Since your localhost endpoint is `/graphql`.

Hope it helps :)